# How to sort an array to a Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array of numbers in an excel spreadsheet which I am trying to sort (all numbers >60) using a user defined vba function and i want  to return the result as a range in the same excel sheet.

I am getting a value error when i run this function in excel.I am not too sure where this error is coming from as  I a new to VBA.I would really appreciate some guidance in resolving this issue.

Array Excel

```
Column A
200
50
23
789
```

---

```
Function trial(number As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim savearray() As Variant
    Dim d As Long

    For Each cell In Range("a3:a6").Cells
        If cell.Value > 60 Then
            d = d + 1
            ReDim Preserve savearray(1 To d)
            savearray(1, d) = cell.Value
            trial = savearray
        End If
    Next cell
End Function
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use a `Function`? Functions are used when you want some value to be returned. You are sorting numbers if I'm not overseeing something can`t you just use the Sort on the worksheet?

Comment: In general, a formula entered in a cell can only return a value to that cell. Use a sub instead.

Comment: Your function doesn't sort anyway, and your parameter is not used.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of work to do on your Sub. However, to help you, below is a way to dynamically build an array:

```
d = 0
For Each cell In Range("A3:A1000")
    If cell.Value > 60 Then
        If d = 0 Then
            ReDim savearray(0 To 0)
        Else
            ReDim Preserve savearray(0 To UBound(savearray) + 1)
        End If
        savearray(d) = cell.Value
        d = d + 1
    End If
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you might want to **rather return a sorted array** and only then, cast results to a `Range`

---

1. First we create a `Function` to sort our array

   ```
   Private Function BubbleSort(ByRef from() As Variant) As Variant()

      Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
      Dim temp As Variant

      For i = LBound(from) To UBound(from) - 1
          For j = i + 1 To UBound(from)
              If from(i) < from(j) Then
                  temp = from(j)
                  from(j) = from(i)
                  from(i) = temp
              End If
          Next j
      Next i

      BubbleSort = from ' returns sorted array

   End Function
   ```
2. Then we create a simple "`Range` replacer"  procedure

   ```
   Private Sub replace_with_sorted(ByVal which As Range)

      Dim arr() As Variant
      arr = Application.Transpose(which)
      arr = BubbleSort(arr)

      which = Application.Transpose(arr)

   End Sub
   ```
3. So the invokation would look the following way:

   ```
   Private Sub test()
       replace_with_sorted Range("A1:A4")
   End Sub
   ```

---

This of course produces the expected result:

[image]

---

**EDIT**: Just noticed you want to sort only values larger than 60.
In that case, simply fill an array with values larger than 60 and use the same application.

```
Private Sub test()
  Dim arr() as Variant: arr = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A4"))
  Dim above60() as Variant
  Dim i as Integer, j as Integer: j = 0

  For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
         If arr(i) > 60 Then
            ReDim Preserve above60(j)
            above60(j) = arr(i)
            j = j + 1
         End If
  Next i

  ReDim arr()
  arr = BubbleSort(above60) 
  ' returns sorted array, do whatever u want with it _
   (place it in whatever range u want, not defined in ur question)


End Sub
```